# Convert random concatenated letter and number cells into a single numerical equivalent?

Tags: google-apps-script

Please see a screen shot of my data:

[image]

Basically I would like to transform this concatenated resulting string `sometextmoretext0.544728.822222222244728.823611111144728.825othertext` (found in cell H6 in example) into whatever this data's numerical equivalent would be. However I can't seem to find a function to do this yet.

If anyone wants to know why:

I would like to make a unique ID column that is based on the unique combination of those columns. I figure all data has some kind of numerical equivalent to a computer, so there is likely to be a way!

Perhaps Apps Script can handle a task like this?

Comment: I guess maybe ASCII equivalents?

Comment: What do you mean by numerical equivalent?

Comment: You can convert string into number with `CODE` formula. But I do not think uniqueness is guaranteed by such conversion.

Comment: Each character is minimum 8 bits which is a number between 0 and 255. How would you combine these to come up with a single number?

Comment: Isn't your concatenation already a "unique ID [...] based on the unique combination of those columns"? Are you thinking about a hash?

Comment: Unicode number values of each character I guess. As such I have currently settled on codifying my text strings to 2 characters and using the `CODE(...)` function for the first character and `CODE(RIGHT(...),1)` for the second character. Perhaps with apps script I could come up with something more elegant and even convert full text strings, but for now my 2 character convention is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To convert each character of a string into an unicode number and concat them:

`=JOIN(" ",ArrayFormula(CODE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(H6,"(.)","$1♦"),"♦"))))`

---

The formula work as follows:

1. Insert a special character `♦` between each characters of the original string

`REGEXREPLACE(H6,"(.)","$1♦")`

2. Split the generated string by the special character `♦`, in order to get the array of the characters

`SPLIT(...,"♦")`

3. Convert each character into an unicode number

`ArrayFormula(CODE(...))`

4. Concat each unicode number with the specified string

`JOIN(" ",...)`

Comment: Well this produces a single number! Thank you. I don't understand what is going on here however. Would you be willing to explain this powerful solution somewhat?

Comment: Added explanation, (and also rearranged the order of the formula for easier understanding).

Comment: Might I ask, what do intend to do with this ID?  Isn't 1,2,3...1001,1002,... unique enough?